# After upgrading to 16.04 LTS , qbittorrent won't open?

Tags: 16.04, qbittorrent

It shows qbittorrent: symbol lookup error: qbittorrent:

undefined symbol:  `_ZN10libtorrent27default_storage_constructorERKNS_12file_storageEPS1_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERNS_9file_poolERKSt6vectorIhSaIhEE`.

I had tried purge completely and tried to install older version,but no luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove --purge qbittorrent libtorrent-rasterbar8
sudo apt-get install qbittorrent
```

Reinstalling qbittorent from the ppa you will get the 3.3.4 version, and that should fix the problem.